# how can I use for /f to pause at the "current" line

Tags: windows, cmd

Is it possible to use the `for /f` command in CMD to read a file incrementally? I'd like to be able to change lines in the file that "haven't been read" (i.e., haven't yet been processed in the loop) but it seems that doing so has no effect.

For example, say my file temp.txt has three lines:

```
one
# two
# three
```

and I use

```
for /f "eol=#" %i in (temp.txt) do @echo %i & sleep 10s
```

When I execute this and then within the first ten seconds remove the hash marks and save the file, I don't get all three lines (as I'm expecting/seeking). I'm expecting that because I've removed the hash marks (within the first 10 seconds) that by the time the loop gets to the second line, it will not skip it because there is no hash mark. It seems that the entire file is read in first before even the first line is processed (or maybe some "large" block of it?). Is there a way to make the loop read each line only when it's being "used" (i.e., to not read-ahead and just wait until it's ready for the next one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`for /F`loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) seems to read the whole text file at once<sup>1</sup>. To see any changes to the given file, it needs to be opened and closed for reading every single line. Anyway, you also have to consider that lines could be inserted or removed, so the output might not be as you expect.

The following code should do what you want -- see all the explanatory `rem` remarks:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Define file path/name here:
set "FILE=%~dpn0.txt"
rem // Determine number of lines - 1:
for /F %%C in ('^< "%FILE%" find /C /V ""') do set /A "CNT=%%C-1"
rem // Iterate through all 0-based line numbers:
for /L %%I in (0,1,%CNT%) do (
    rem // Wait for some time:
    > nul timeout /T 3 /NOBREAK
    rem // Read a single line in a sub-routine:
    call :SUB "%FILE%" %%I
)
exit /B


:SUB
    rem // Prepare `skip` option for `for /F` loop (to skip current line number - 1):
    if %~2 equ 0 (set "SKIP=") else (set "SKIP=skip=%~2")
    rem /* Read single line; `findstr` prefixes them with a line number to preserve
    rem    empty lines (remember that `for /F` skips them otherwise, so letting them
    rem    alone would lead to `for /F` returning the next non-empty line): */
    for /F "%SKIP% delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%~1"') do (
        rem // Store the read line, including the line number prefix:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Exit the loop, hence skip the rest of the file:
        goto :END
    )
:END
    rem /* Return the read line with the line number prefix removed;
    rem    delayed expansion avoids trouble with special characters: */
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (
        for /F "delims= eol=#" %%K in ("!LINE:*:=!") do endlocal & echo(%%K
    ) || endlocal
    exit /B
```

This script sticks to certain line numbers, therefore:

- when you insert lines:

  - there are as many lines at the end missing at the output as you inserted;
  - there are as many lines returned twice as you inserted before the currently processed line;
- when you remove lines:

  - there are as many empty lines appended to the end as you removed;
  - there are as many lines skipped as you removed before the currently processed line;

---

<sub>1) I experimented with a file containing 64K lines with 8K length each, changing the last line while letting `for /F` read the file, and the change was not reflected in the output; there could be a size limit though for this behaviour, but I could not yet find out; also the application to modify the text file play its role here, because it might actually work on a temporary copy rather than the given file, so wrong conclusions might be drawn.</sub>

Comment: Wow! That's pretty impressive. It took me a bit to follow it - thanks much for the comments. This doesn't work though because the eol=# in the SUB never matches because you've prefixed the line with the number (and a colon, both via find command). If you try this on the original sample you get all three lines (should get only one). No need to refine though, I believe I can take it from here. Thanks again! Very helpful.

Comment: correction: above should be "both via findstr command" (incorrectly typed as find rather than findstr).